# Unable to access WCF Service from Client machine

Tags: wcf, windows-services, client

Unable to access WCF Service from Client machine

- I have three projects : WCF Service (VS-2008), Windows Service (VS-2008), Client (VS-2005)
- The WCF service has netTcpBinding
- This service is hosted as a windows service and not on IIS

The base address for both the service (WCF and Windows) is

```
net.tcp://localhost:8010/WCFService.Service1/
```

Now when i add a service reference to the client project which is on VS-2005, It updates my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="netTcpEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
                    transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"         maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8010/WCFService.Service1/"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpEndPoint"
                contract="Client.Service1.IService1"
                name="netTcpEndPoint">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/server17.domain.com" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And adds Service1.map file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceReference>
    <ProxyGenerationParameters
        ServiceReferenceUri="net.tcp://server17:8010/WCFService.Service1/"
        Name="Service1"
        NotifyPropertyChange="False"
        UseObservableCollection="False">
    </ProxyGenerationParameters>
    <EndPoints>
        <EndPoint
            Address="net.tcp://localhost:8010/WCFService.Service1/"
            BindingConfiguration="netTcpEndPoint"
            Contract="Client.Service1.IService1"
            >
        </EndPoint>
    </EndPoints>
</ServiceReference>
```

When I call any of the service methods I get an error stating

> Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8010/WCFService.Service1/.
>   The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0063936. TCP
>   error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8010.

At least it should be `net.tcp://server17:8010/WCFService.Service1/`

I have already tried to replace `localhost` with `server17` in the client project... but no luck

What should I change to make it working? please help.

> This is my WCF Service's App.config which is same as windows service's
>   app.config : as requested by Tim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFService.ServiceBehavior" 
        name="WCFService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" 
          name="netTcpEndPoint" contract="WCFService.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="mexTcpEndPoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8010/WCFService.Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFService.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are your service and your client running on the same machine?
This is definitly a network related error, so i guess your service is not running or does not bind the port 8010. Open a command prompt and try to connect with "telnet localhost 8010" on the machine where your service is running. If you don't get a connection, your service is definitly not listening on port 8010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess I'd check three things:

1. When you add the service reference to your client, are you adding it from `net.tcp://localhost:8010/WCFService.Service1/`, or are you adding it from `net.tcp://server17:8010/WCFService.Service1/`?
2. If you're adding it from server17, try using the fully qualified name of the server - i.e., server17.mydomain.com or whatever it is.
3. The connection error is probably related to the endpoint address you're using - the client is passing in a serverPrincipalName of "host/server17.domain.com", but you're attempting to connect to localhost.

No guarantees any of the above are the root cause, but it gives you a place to start.

**EDIT**

You specify the locahost in the baseAddress element, but you don't specify anything in the address attribute of the endpiont element.  That's probably why it's still going to localhost.

Modify the config file for your service to either change the baseAddress to:

```
<baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://server17:8010/WCFService.Service1/" />
</baseAddresses>
```

or drop the baseAddresses and specify the address in your endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://server17:8010/WCFService.Service1/"
          binding="netTcpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration=""
          name="netTcpEndPoint" 
          contract="WCFService.IService1" />
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Hi tim,
Thanks for your reply.

i have added reference using net.tcp://server17:8010/WCFService.Service1/ URI
and as you suggested, i have also used fully qualified names, but still its not working and giving the same error...

I am wondering why it is trying to contact localhost instead of server17?
AND Why there are URIs with localhost even after i added service reference from Server17?
(as you can see that from the above given config and map file).

Is that related to the baseaddress in the WCF service - app.config which points to localhost?

Comment: @Bravo - it might be related. I wouldn't think (off the top of my head) that it would be since you're explictly setting the fully qualified address. Try removing it and see if that does the trick. Also, post your service's app.config file.

Comment: ok Tim, i have posted my service's config file, please look at the question statement

Comment: oh yes, i should have specified something in the address attribute of the endpoint element, but since i am new to WCF, i dont know what to specify there :) . Can you help me with this or just tell me what we need to specify there.

Comment: i think we are half way there, i no more see localhost in any of my projects, but i am still getting the same error about localhost

Comment: ok...got it resolved, thanks :)

I forgot to update the app.config file of the main project which had the URI as localhost... how can i forget this... however, thank for your every single effort to solve my problem